# How to use correctly IN filter in Acumatica Report Designer?

Tags: acumatica

A bit new in Acumatica, I've been tasked to update a report which it in on itself is pretty easy, just adding a new value to a filter.

The part of the query I'm modifying is:

```
( [INRegister].[TransferType] = '1' AND [INTran].[TranDate] BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '20220101 0:0:0.000') AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '20230112 0:0:0.000') AND ( [INRegister].[DocType] = 'I' OR [INRegister].[DocType] = 'A') AND ( [INTran].[ReasonCode] = 'Null' OR [INTran].[ReasonCode] = 'BAJACADUCA' OR [INTran].[ReasonCode] = 'INISSUED' OR [INTran].[ReasonCode] = 'Null') AND ( [InventoryItem].[PreferredVendorID] = NULL OR NULL IS NULL ))
ORDER BY [InventoryItem].[ItemClassID], [InventoryItem].[PreferredVendorID], [INTran].[TranDate] OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```

I need to use In when ReasonCode is INISSUED because it should have another value (BAJAMERCADERIA) too but everytime I try to use the In filter the second value is ignored or truncated when I check the trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second value is primarily used for the between clause.  Have you tried a comma delimited list in value1?  i.e. BAJAMERCADERIA,INISSUED

Comment: I have, but the values are truncated when I call the report

Comment: Did some more research and found this:   The “Is In” operator doesn’t behave like SQL “IN”. It accepts only one value as an input: the name of a custom filter. Some custom filters are dynamically generated by the system, such as “@MyGroups”, others are built buy a user with sufficient access to the Filters screen (CS209010).

Comment: That actually makes sense, weird that in is not an implementation by default. Thanks a lot.